# WPF Navigation TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm trying to create treeview menu where any click on an node would then change a canvas to load an xaml file based on that nodes name.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could probably compile xaml in run time, but wouldn't you rather simply create compiled user controls, get a ctor for them using reflection and call it + add them as children when required?
you can put them in separate assemblies (say in a different directory or use some naming convention), and poll each time (say on each tree view node mouse click, or employ some caching policy) to see if there are any new assemblies.